# Android Application closing for no reason

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i started learning android development about 2 days ago.. So was trying out with a basic application to increment and decrement.
Everything is okay but when i'm testing the application even on the emulator, i get a message "Unfortunately, application "
I tried debugging the code and found that Even after declaring a statement findViewById(), my variables are pointing to null. And i think that's the reason for this error.. heres my code, in MainActivity.java. Please help me out!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

/* Your original code */
/*
TextView sum;
Button increment;
Button decrement;
*/
int total;


/* My interpretation */
protected static TextView sum;
protected static Button increment;
protected static Button decrement;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.findViewById();

    total = 0;

    increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            total++;
            sum.setText("Sum is "+total);
        }
    });

    decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            total--;
            sum.setText("Sum is "+total);
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

/* Your original code (moved to fragment) */
/*
private void findViewById() {
    sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);          // sum points to null
    increment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inc);  //increment points to null
    decrement = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dec);  // decrement points to null
}
*/
```

EDIT ::

placeholder fragment ::

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /* added */
    Context ctx = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;

        /* added */
        init();
    }

    /* added */
    private void init()
    {
    final View v = getView();

    ctx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        MainActivity.sum = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);          // sum points to null
        MainActivity.increment = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.inc);  //increment points to null
        MainActivity.decrement = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dec);  // decrement points to null
    }
}
```

here is the layout ::

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.vishal.Simplecalc.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:text="@string/sumView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/inc"
    android:text="@string/inc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dec"
    android:text="@string/dec"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `no reason` seem big words...

Comment: if you haven't found it yet, adb logcat is a great tool in your sdk; if you are rooted, try out logcat extreme; it's running on my n7 50% of the time; it has a nifty floating window feature that you'll enjoy

Comment: I mean i cant figure out the reason, sorry for that! 
I'll add the log cat shortly, but Is everything fine in the code?

Comment: I looked into the log cat it shows the null pointer exception

Comment: Try removing the tools:context tags, some are pointing to the fragment, some to the activity. Not sure if that'll help, but it might work.

Comment: hmm but, that's auto generated?

Comment: I think those are just lint tags, the error somewhere else, I believe.

Comment: What are you doing in placeholder fragment, if that's setting a layout, then you have an error, as the variables are null.

Comment: I removed it. But Problem still exists
The nulllpointerException is pointing to line 31 i.e

   increment.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener)

Comment: I'll edit the question for place holder fragment

Comment: I've added it have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here (you haven't added the name for your xml layout).

I'm guessing you're probably confusing your layouts and just posted `fragment_main.xml` which actually has the content your code is believing to be held in `activity_main`, which causes your code to return nulls when you're assigning the `findViewById()`

Comment: so i should copy the contents of fragment_main (which i posted) in to activity_main?

Comment: Oh! i see 1 thing here, the setContentView is set to activity_main

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: this seems to fix a part of the problem but it raises an exception in if condition over SavedInstanceState

Comment: The code you're showing right now shouldn't be working at all. The way you're correcting it (i.e. moving the code from xml to xml ) might work, but it all depends...

Comment: It is working now.. I changed the setContentView as setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main) and removed the condition check on savedInstanceState

But i havent used activity_main anywhere.. is that a problem?

Comment: not really. Your visual components are in your fragments.

Comment: Anyhow, glad to be helpful. If you consider the question solved, please mark it as such!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that PlaceholderFragment is setting a new layout, and that doesn't allow the text to be changed.

Comment: Really?  Wouldn't it just fail to compile?

Comment: It may or may not, but can you post the layout?

Comment: This can be a comment.

Comment: I have declared all the id's.. 
Btw, I'm new and I dont understand how to post this logcat.. :(

Comment: Click on Windows->Show View->Logcat->Copy and Paste, but can you post the layout? All you need to do is open that and copy and paste.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post big comments

Comment: i managed to take a screenshot.. here is the error...

http://screencast.com/t/QejwDp7w

Comment: I've posted the layout

Comment: log cat is too big shall i post the entire thing??

Comment: @Vishay Sharma: That's the way you're expected to.

Comment: okay i'll post it but the preview is so complicated and tuff to understand anyway i'll post it!

Comment: too big! it says i can post only 3000 characters :/

Comment: Anyway, it's a NullPointerException, so something is being used before it's declared.

Comment: @Vyger: Null at Increment.setOnClickListener

Comment: OK, I'm thinking to something that happened to me too - then I solved it and I'm not thinking to it for a long time. It works so: in the Main Activity (I extend from FragmentActivity, but it should be no issue) I open the Fragment. IN THE FRAGMENT I initialize the Activity controls (which I declared protected and static, so they are visible). Then In the Activity (where they are declared) I use them. It's a matter of order: what happens **before** and what happens **after**.

Comment: oh! that goes over my head, I'm sorry!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by opening the fragment and editing?

Comment: I edited your code as required. It should work, as it works in my app. If not, you might do some minor corrections. But in principle it should work. I assuming that all the controls are in the Fragment layout, not in the Activity layout (which is only an EMPTY placeholder for the fragment itself). In my code, I used a centralized onClick listener (set in xml code), but this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It is working now.. 
I changed the setContentView as setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main)
and removed the condition check on savedInstanceState

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be because of emulators, create new emulator or try it with your real device .